# Intro Level Product Function

Tags: python

I am tasked with creating a function that will accept up to 5 inputs and return their products. I have gone with two different approaches to solve this problem, but each presents their own shortcomings. Here is approach one:

```
def mult(*args):
    product = 1
    for x in args:
        product *=x
    return product
```

This code does exactly what I need it to, but since I used *args, it accepts any variable number of functions, when I need it to only accept up to 5. Is there a way I can limit args to just up to 5 inputs? If not, here is my other approach:

```
def my_function(param1, param2='x', param3='x', param4='x', param5='x'):
    return (param1*param2*param3*param4*param5)
```

This code does what I need only in the case that the number of inputs is greater than or equal to 5, but if it is less it does not return the product. I am sure this problem arises in part because of the default values I've assigned to the parameters. I am just not sure on what default values I need to use to ensure that even if I present less than 5 inputs, the function will still return their product.

Comment: What about checking `len(args)` inside the function and raising a `ValueError` (or similar) if the length > 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values should be 1, since it will just multiply everything else by 1, if you don't give it anything, meaning it will stay the same.

For the `param1` i would set the default value to 0, since if you don't have any inputs it would output `1*1*1*1*1` instead, which would be 1.

```
def my_function(param1=0, param2=1, param3=1, param4=1, param5=1):
    return (param1*param2*param3*param4*param5)
```

Using your first approach, you could only run the function if the number of arguments passed in `len(args)` is lower than or equal to 5 like this:

```
def mult(*args):
    if not (len(args) > 5):
        product = 1
        for x in args:
            product *=x
        return product
```

Comment: You are superb! This is exactly what I needed and I wish I would have thought of it because it makes perfect sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The original poster has indicated satisfaction with @Mark's answer, which performs no action when the number of arguments exceeds 5. For possible future benefit I will post two alternative methods, each of which has a different behavior.

First, if we want to make certain that the number of arguments is limited to 5, and warn the user if otherwise, we can raise an exception:

```
def mult1(*args):
    if len(args) > 5:
        raise Exception('Number of arguments must not exceed 5.')
    product = 1
    for x in args:
        product *= x
    return product
```

Second, if we want to accept any number of arguments without raising an exception, but only multiply the first 5:

```
def mult2(*args):
    depth = min(5, len(args))
    product = 1
    for x in args[:depth]:
        product *= x
    return product
```